# Guzzle and react Promise cause infine loop

Tags: promise, guzzle6, reactphp

I use [Guzzle 6](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)  to call asynchrous request and I then use [React Promise/Deferred](https://github.com/reactphp/promise) and Event loop , then I use [php-react-block](https://github.com/clue/php-block-react) to get result by resolved.

Firstly  I send http Request as following:

```
public function callService($endpoint){
    $requestDeferred = new React\Promise\Deferred();
    $requestParams = new Request("POST", $endpoint, $header, $message);
    $client = new Client();//Guzzle  http client
    $client->sendAsync($requestParams)->then(
        function (ResponseInterface $res) use($requestDeferred) {
            // $res->getStatusCode() . "\n";
            $requestDeferred->resolve($res->getBody()->getContents());
        }, 
        function (RequestException $e) use($requestDeferred) {
            $requestDeferred->reject();
        }
    );
    return $requestDeferred->promise();
}
```

After I call this method as following

```
$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$requestPromise = $this->callService( $endpoint);
$responseXml = Clue\React\Block\await($requestPromise, $loop);// I want to block/wait to until promise is resolved and get resolved value.
```

But when I call  Clue\React\Block\await($requestPromise, $loop) , the system loops infinetly and any promise can not be resolved. Also I added queue->run() method to run method of related event (LibEvent).  But system still loops infinetly.

Why the system loops infinetly?

Thanks for your helps

Comment: Is your promise eventually resolved when you don't call await()?

Comment: yes  ,  the promise can be eventually resolved without calling await()